# What does 没有最好只有更好 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[In the following sentence over 华人街](https://www.huarenjie.com/thread-5510973-1-1.html):

> 从我这几天的观察来看，大部分都比较喜欢欧美国家，所以我把意大利早点介绍，**意大利文化真的是没有最好只有更好的**，意大利的强势专业绝对是艺术，美院也是特别的有名气，佛罗伦萨美院等等，但是缺点就是经济比较弱，大学毕业以后工作确实不是特别好找，意大利人很懒，生活节奏比较慢，但免学费。

I don't understand the bold part. Specifically, what does the sentence including 没有最好只有更好 mean? I'm fine with all the other sentences, but don't understand what it means in the bold part...

It starts with something like - *Italian culture is really not only the best...?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 意大利文化 // 真的是 // 没有最好 // 只有更好的 
>   Italian culture really doesn't have the best (thing), only better (things).

The 《没有最好，只有更好的》 is the quality linked to by the copula 是。

With some more thought you could surely find a more fluent translation.

Anyway, it's an elegant way of saying that Italian fine arts and cultural heritages are so many (common, widespread) that you can't just single out THE best one, but they all rival each other.